# GDI Antialiasing not working well on Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, fonts, windows-server-2008, system.drawing

I'm using System.Drawing to generate some images on the fly that include a base image plus some stretched / scaled text. Everything is nice and neat on my LOCALHOST environment, but when I publish to my server (Server 2008), I lose some of the antialiasing and the image quality gets grainy.

Here is an example copied from my local environment (Windows 7), and then from my server (Server 2008)

Windows 7:

[image]

Windows 2008:

[image]

As you can see, the images are the same size, and the fonts are scaled the same as well. The Server version doesn't seem to have anti-aliasing to smooth out the edges. Here's the main piece of code: imgSign and grSign are an established Image and Graphics object with a set size / background color onto which the text is to be scaled / drawn.

```
'Requested size of test
Dim textSize As SizeF = grSign.MeasureString(textString, font)
Dim intTextWidth As Integer = textSize.Width
Dim intTextHeight As Integer = textSize.Height

'Create image to hold text
Dim img As Drawing.Image = New Bitmap(intTextWidth, intTextHeight)
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)

'Smoothing mode
gr.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
gr.TextRenderingHint = Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

'Scale Text
Dim sngScaleWidth As Single = imgSign.Width / intTextWidth
If sngScaleWidth > 1 Then sngScaleWidth = 1 'Don't scale down width if it doesn't need to be
Dim sngScaleHeight As Single = imgSign.Height / intTextHeight
grSign.ScaleTransform(sngScaleWidth, sngScaleHeight)

'Draw text
gr.DrawString(textString, font, Brushes.White, 0, 0)
```

Is there some functionality that isn't there on Server 2008 that I have to work around, or a switch I can set to increase the quality, or do I need to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try also to set on your Graphics gr this settings

```
gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
gr.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

to archive better quality, and double check that the fonts that you are using is the same on both systems.

Comment: That seems to have helped, but there's still a noticeable reduction in quality between systems the more I scale text. See below:


Windows 7: http://signshop.c2itconsulting.net/samples/windows7a-z.png


Server 2008: 
http://signshop.c2itconsulting.net/services/drawtext.ashx?text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&fontName=Roadgeek%202005%20Series%205B.ttf&fontSize=70&w=400&h=70

Comment: Got it working. I needed to set the InterpolationMode and PixelOffset mode on my grSign object which controls drawing objects onto the background image, instead of just on the gr object, which controls drawing of the text.

Final result is at http://signshop.c2itconsulting.net. Custom fonts installed on the fly, random string lengths, and what I consider some great text scaling and smoothing to fit text into a desired box.

Comment: @ChetatC2IT I am glad that you final find it, and I help a bit.